# HDMI splitter @ 4K

Tags: pcb-design, altium, high-speed, hdmi

I want to make HDMI splitter which support 4K resolution,

I have already found some IC's which are cable for splitting HDMI, but unfortunately non of them supported 4K and they only supported 1080P/60.

I will appreciate of anybody which have knowledge and experience about this topic for helping me for finding the (HDMI 4K splitter) and guide me if there is any critical noticeable rules which I have to do for making this project.

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Buying an off-the-shelf one is not an option?

Comment: No, the company which I am working in it, ask me to I make PCB for them.So i can not buy it from the market

Comment: @a2640 You will need a multi GHz scope and know how to do high speed design, transmission lines, matching ect. It would probably also be best to have a PCB editor like altium that helps you calculate speeds and matching for diff pairs

Comment: thank for your response.I am working with altium and I have some experience with high speed design and length matching,Impedance control... .But this project I think would be very hard, I have got headache during these day and dont know understand how to to that to be honest with u.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the entire product design problem is being posted before conducting any research on the requirement's bandwith, meta data signaling, or how existing solutions work.  If nothing else buy one and take it apart to see what is inside in terms of both components and geometry.

Comment: Since you tagged this with [tag:pcb-design], it means that you're looking for a chip that you can put on your board. Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this company makes what you are looking for. However they have minimum order of 4,500 pieces:

http://www.ite.com.tw/en/product/view?mid=103

It could also be done with an FPGA but would require investment in HDMI IP and cost would be quite high.

Comment: Than you for your answer, yes I found this chip before by opening one HDMI slitter 4K, But unfortunately I could not find any evaluation kit or references schematic which belongs to this chip.Do know how can I find them ?

Comment: You would have to contact ITE, they are in Taiwan